# How can I paint a spinner on a plantuml wireframe?

Tags: spinner, plantuml, wireframe

I am trying to make a wireframe using the salt diagram type of plantuml, but I noticed it doesn't have the default spinner component.

How could that effect be achieved?

## starting code

```
@startuml
salt
{
  {^"Compra"
    Número de boletos: |"5"
  }

  Total: $0.00
  [Pagar]


}
@enduml
```

[image: starting wireframe where text field should be replaced by spinner]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have accomplished so far and it looks pretty consistent:

```
@startuml
salt
{
  {^"Compra"
    Número de boletos:| {+5|<&caret-top>
    .|<&caret-bottom>}
  }

  Total: $0.00
  [Pagar]


}
@enduml
```

[image: spinner attempt on plantuml wireframe]

Basically I use the braces to put two lines with their up arrow and down arrow icons respectively

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post while searching for the same thing and found that the 'elevator' standard icon from OpenIconic works quite well:

```
@startsalt
{
    Spinner: | {+100 <&elevator>}  
}
@endsalt
```

[image: Elevator Icon Salt Spinner Example]